# How to invert an array with recursion passing two parameters?

Tags: c

I made an inverter the easy way, with the array as a parameters and two ints that are the start and the end. The problem I got stuck with is coding a function that gets as parameters the array and a number which represent how many values the array have. Any idea?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far and provide a [mcve].

Comment: The only idea I have so far is that there must be a bug somewhere in the code you didn't show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a base case for length 0 and 1, and for the recursive step, swap the first and last element, increment the array pointer, and call itself with length-2. This code does the trick:

```
void invert(int* arr, int len) {
    if(len == 0) {
        return;
    }
    else if(len == 1) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        int temp = arr[0];
        arr[0] = arr[len-1];
        arr[len-1] = temp;
        invert(arr+1, len-2);
    }
}
```

A working example: https://www.onlinegdb.com/fork/r1QonMsCf

Comment: Fixed to use recursion (although iteration is really better here, unless you can guarantee tail call optimization will be used by the compiler).

Comment: It worked thank you! I dont understand how the arr+1 parameter work. How can you pass an array+1 Is that a number? How can it be if the parameter Is an array?

Comment: An array in C is really stored as a pointer to the first element. When I declare `int c[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};` what I really have is the ints stored contiguously in memory and `c` decays to a pointer to the first element. When you increment a pointer, it points at the next element (so `c+1` will point to the second element in that array). So in `invert`, when I make the recursive call `invert(arr+1, len-2)`, I'm really telling it to start at the next element, and ignore both the first and last element.